# Fourier Series of f(x) = 1 (exponential version)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Problem:** I'm trying to find just the Fourier series of f(x) = 1 from 0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ $\pi$ using the exponential definition of the coefficients (f(x) = 0 from $-\pi \leq x < 0$). I'm running into a divide by $0$ problem.

So I know that:
$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{(-inx)} \,dx $$
$ f(x) = 1 $ and integral of $e^{-inx}$ is $\frac{-e^{-i*\pi*n}}{in}$

Integrating, I get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} (\frac{-e^{-i*\pi*n}}{in} + \frac{1}{in})$ = $\frac{1}{2\pi} (\frac{-(-1)^{-n}+1)}{in})$$

So this seems like it should be the formula for the $c_n$?

But I don't think it is. Because we have to take the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}$. But $c_0$ = $\infty$.

Also my understanding is that for Fourier Series, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx} = f(x)$ for all $x$. But Wolfram Alpha shows that's not the case here. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you wrote the integral of $e^{-inx}$ when $n=0$ wrong! For $n=0$ $$c_0 = \frac1{2\pi } \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^0 dx = \int_0^\pi dx = \pi$$

Comment: Integrationing results in $c_0=1$ and not in $c_0=\pi$. So the Fourier expansion is $1$, as it should be.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Ah good point! Yeah of course you're right that $c_0$ = 1. Oh I see, of course you can't do the integration the way I did when n = 0 so I have to make that a separate case. Thank you!